# Access Context from another activty in Android

Tags: android, android-context

I have a Main class and another two classes named WebServicesClass and DynamicHeightAdpater.

I am creating an instance of DynamicHeightAdpater in WebServicesClass for which I need the context of MainActivity but I am not sure how to point it. The way by which I am calling throws a NullPointerException.

**CODE :**

**MainActivity :**

```
static Context context;
context = this.context;
```

**WebServicesClass :**

```
new DynamicHeightAdapter(MainActivity.context, 1, rowItems);
```

But it throws a null pointer exception and I am sure that it is due to the context cause I tried to print it and it threw NullPointer.

Comment: I don't get ya. WebServices is a separate class and I am creating an instance of another class in it.

Comment: As you can see in the inheritance chain, an Activity _is_ a Context ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html ), so there is no point is storing the context in a static variable. Just pass your MainActivity instance to the constructor of your DynamicHeightAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to take a look at the [Android application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). You can store context there and retrieve it, when needed:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mAppContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mAppContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the application's context. Useful for classes that need a Context
     * but don't inherently have one.
     * 
     * @return application context
     */
    public static Context getAppContext() {
    return mAppContext;
    }
```

Comment: I would also suggest to take a look at this fantastic article about the Context in Android http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/ to make sure you are using the Context properly.

Comment: Thnx, it was a great article!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest passing the Context to the `WebServicesClass` object in it's constructor, and having a member variable to keep it... something like

```
public class WebServicesClass
{
    private Context mContext;
    ...

    public WebServicesClass(Context c) // constructor
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    void someOtherFunction()
    {
         new DynamicHeightAdapter(mContext, 1, rowItems);
    }
}
```